# What properties of a material make for good radiation shielding?

Tags: radiation, cosmic-radiation

What is the requirement of a material to deflect or block radioactive particles? Is it the number of electrons surrounding the atom? The density of the nucleus? The strength of the bond of the atoms in the molecule? What gives a material its radiation blocking properties?

Comment: It's a wide field given the different types and properties of radiation (neutron, alpha, proton, beta, gamma) and requirements (lead is good when you don't have to haul it into orbit, water is good if you do). I suspect this is 'too broad' to be effectively answered as it stands.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_protection

Comment: @Hohmannfan Agree, that covers what's on topic here. The rest is a broad physics question.